# Observer foundation adapter

Tags: angular, angular-material, mdc-components

After npm install and npm start I get this error with observer

```
Error: node_modules/@material/base/observer-foundation.d.ts:25:75 - error TS2344: Type 'Adapter' does not satisfy the constraint '{}'.

25 export declare class MDCObserverFoundation<Adapter> extends MDCFoundation<Adapter> {
                                                                             ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@material/base/observer-foundation.d.ts:25:44
    25 export declare class MDCObserverFoundation<Adapter> extends MDCFoundation<Adapter> {
                                                  ~~~~~~~
    This type parameter might need an `extends {}` constraint.
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ui-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "@material/form-field": "^14.0.0",
    "@material/grid-list": "^4.0.0",
    "@material/theme": "^14.0.0",
    "@material/toolbar": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

**ok. I see similar problem** https://github.com/angular/components/issues/25657 but when I do

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

nothing change. Still this same error.

[image]

Going from:
export declare class MDCObserverFoundation extends MDCFoundation {
to:
export declare class MDCObserverFoundation<Adapter extends {}> extends MDCFoundation {
in file node_modules/@material/base/observer-foundation.d.ts:25:75
seems to fix it.

How fix this withou workaround

Comment: @Dai removed from C# tag

Comment: Looks like it's a pending issue : https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/7727